# Non-tabs in quicktabs

Tags: 6, blocks

I'm using [QuickTabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) on a Drupal 6 site. I have a block in which I need to have some normal tabs and some pseudo-tabs, which look like tabs but are actually just links that load a whole new page. Is there a way to do this with quicktabs configuration? In particular, could I use `theme_quicktabs_tabs()` for this? If so, where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

You could always copy the tab HTML and put it somewhere outside the QuickTabs output, and then position them using CSS where you want them on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by putting a [theme_quicktabs_tab](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!quicktabs!quicktabs.module/function/theme_quicktabs_tabs/6) override in template.php.